# Manipulating with the double pointers across function calls in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, nullpointerexception

My Scenario is as follows:

In the caller function::

```
IDirect3DSurface9 * surf = null;
Func(&surf);
hr = surf->LockRect(, , );  // THROWS an EXCEPTION BCOZ "surf" is still null. Dont know why ??
```

In the CALLED function:

```
Func(IDirect3DSurface9 **surfReceive)
{
   surfReceive= new IDirect3DSurface9*[10];
  IDirect3DSurface9* surfcreate = NULL;

        hr = xyz->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(  width, 
                                                            height, 
                                                            formt, 
                                                            D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, 
                                                            &surfcreate, 
                                                            NULL);
        if (FAILED(hr)) 
            return hr;

        surfReceive[0] = surfcreate;
}
```

My doubt is that, in the CALLER (as I have shown in the code above), the surf is still null even after the caller returns back. And it throws exception when I call LockRect() on the surf as below.

```
hr = surf->LockRect(, , );
```

**It's important to note that "CreateOffscreenPlainSurface() " call is returning Success and also "surfcreate" stores the right value and hence the surfReceive[0] also stores correct value. But I think I am making mistake in the way I access this in the CALLER.**

Comment: Please indent your code properly...

Comment: Welcome to memory leaks and a dozen other problems as a result of bad coding practices

Answer (score 1):

Your code is full of bad and wrong- it also exhibits exception unsafety and DRY violation and memory leaks, in addition to the stated problem. The problem, exactly, is that you are not aware of the difference between pointers and values. When you assign to `surfReceive`, then you are simply wiping out the original value and the new value is never returned. In addition, you are going to have *fun* deleting it later.

You can tell this can never work, because you attempt to return a pointer to an array of pointers where the function caller expects a regular pointer.

Use class-based code, gain clarity, safety, and performance all in one go.

```
struct COMDeleter {
    template<typename T> void operator()(T* p) {
        p->Release();
    }
};
void CheckD3DResult(HRESULT hr) {
#ifdef _DEBUG
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        __debugbreak();
    }
#endif
}
std::unique_ptr<IDirect3DSurface9, COMDeleter> Func() {
    IDirect3DSurface9* temp = nullptr;
    CheckD3DResult(xyz->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(
        width, 
        height, 
        formt, 
        D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, 
        &temp, 
        NULL));
    return std::unique_ptr<IDirect3DSurface9, COMDeleter>(temp);
}
std::unique_ptr<IDirect3DSurface9, COMDeleter> surf = Func();
CheckD3DResult(surf->LockRect(...));
```

This code respects exceptions, guarantees memory cleanup, and comes at least close to respecting DRY.

Comment: Since, I dont know much about the template usage.  Can you kindly explain this a little. I see CheckD3DResult() called @ 2 places. Pardon me if I am asking silly question. I am new to this. So plz can you detaildly explain this. It would be very helpful.

Comment: @codeLover: `unique_ptr` is a class that guarantees to clean up the pointer when it is destroyed. `COMDeleter` just means that, when you clean up this pointer, use the COM `Release()` function instead of `delete`. The template parameters are just the type of pointer you wish to hold, and the destructor (`COMDeleter` in this case). Thanks to this class, it is guaranteed that the above code will never leak memory even in the case of exception. The `CheckD3DResult` function just means you don't have to check the HRESULT every time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain about what'd you expect from `Func`, but this definitely won't work.

You pass `Func` a pointer to an **already** allocated (on the stack) pointer to whatever. Inside `Func` you **reassign** your argument (which is a pointer to an already allocated pointer to whatever) to the address you've just **allocated** (on heap).

I'd say don't allocate anything, just `surfReceive` in a call to `CreateOffscreenPlainSurface`. To access the pointer-to-whatever just use `*surfReceive`.

However you, for the reason I don't understand, allocate an array of 10 pointers-to-whatever.

Comment: But if I use surfReceive in "CreateOffscreenPlainSurface", it is a double pointer right ? Also I can't avoid this double pointer bcoz i would need to access the surface in the CALLER also.